# Запуск двух файлов через ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript

Есть файлик foo.ts, и запускаю программу командой `ts-node src/foo.ts`, но он стал слишком большой, и хочется его разбить.

Вынес во второй файл, и запускается `ts-node src/bar.ts`.

Можно ли запустить сразу два файла одной командой?

Comment: через тот же npm, к примеру, можно

Comment: @InDevX имеете ввиду два дочерних процесса?

Comment: Нет. Имею ввиду добавить [run-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) комманду можно

Comment: Я вот как раз таки и не знаю как написать такую команду =)

Comment: в package.json есть секция script. Туда вписываешь свою комманду, аля `"start": "ts-node src/file1.ts && ts-node src/file2.ts",` и потом запустить можно `npm run start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно одновременно запускать обе программы то решение такое:

установи https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently и тогда в `package.json` можно будет записать такой пускач:

```
  "scripts": {
    "task1": "ts-node src/file1.ts",
    "task2": "ts-node src/file2.ts",
    "start": "concurrently \"yarn task1\" \"yarn task2\""
  },
```

Если программы нужно запускать по очереди то сгодится такой пускач:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/file1.ts && ts-node src/file2.ts"
  },
```